# c create a string on heap

Tags: c, string, heap-memory, string.h

I need to create a string on the heap, I was wondering if there is something similar already included in the standard libraries, or do I have to implement it myself (using malloc())?

Comment: Why -1? I Think this is not that bad question at all....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `strdup()` (the latter is POSIX, not standard C).

It is not totally clear what you mean by "implement it myself (using `malloc()`)" -- what exactly is there to implement?

Comment: Do not forget to allocate extra space for the terminating NUL-character!

Comment: What I wanted to ask if there is a standard function (i.e. "strmk")
that gets a char* and returns a pointer to memory on the heap.
Guess there isn't, and I have to create that function myself.

Comment: @Bg1987: If you simply want to create a heap-allocated copy of the given string, that's what `strdup()` does.